# How to use a network printer in a different room?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I have a Brother network printer, but it can no longer be next to my home router. I do have wireless network set up. What would be the most inexpensive solution to print without using a long cable?

Comment: would you have a wireless printer? or a wired printer? I the later case, you might need a wireless adapter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wireless bridge will join a wired device to a wireless network.  Something like a Linksys WET54G.  It has a bunch of ports and can be configured to be a client of the wireless network.

If you are happy to experiment, then I would get a cheap WRT54G or similar - a cheap wireless router that is compatible with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/).  You replace the linksys firmware with dd-wrt and you can convert the router into various types of wireless extender (or remain a wireless router).  This gives you flexibility down the track if you want to do different things, and often costs less than a dedicated wireless bridge.